# JavaFx handle dragging nodes from FXML controller of node or main?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, nodes, drag

I am trying to drag some custom nodes. These nodes are added as children to an AnchorPane, as defined in the Controller of the root FXML:

```
package sample;

import ...

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    AnchorPane anchorPane;

    public void add() {
        try {
            // Node.fxml is the custom node object
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Node.fxml"));
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(root);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Should I handle my node dragging within the root FXML controller or within the FXML controller of the draggable node itself?

If I should do it within the root FXML controller, how do I do this? Calling FXMLLoader.Load() just references an FXML file, and so I can't attach mouse events to it.

I'm pretty new to Java and JavaFx, so anything is helpful. (not a beginner to programming, however).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `FXMLLoader.load()` returns a `Node`. Why can't you attach event handlers to it?

Comment: I think @fabian is on to something here. Create a method that takes a node as argument, that attaches the relevent drag-event listeners to it. I think that could be a slick solution

Comment: @fabian ahh, I didn't realise that! I had checked the docs but I didn't notice that Parent extends Node. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fabian and @Gikkman I figured out a solution to my problem.
My error was not understanding that Parent extends Node -- I had assumed that I needed to reference something else.

To implement the dragging functionality that I wanted, I created a function that has a Node input variable (thanks @Gikkman) - this Node object can then have event handlers attached to it. Since Parent extends Node (which I didn't realise), I can easily use the FXMLLoader.Load() as input.

So I then have:

```
package sample;

import ...

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    AnchorPane anchorPane;

    public void add() {
        try {
            // Node.fxml is the custom node object
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Node.fxml"));
            // Sets the EventHandlers for dragging
            dragNode(root);
            // Adds the node to the scene
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(root);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Handles all dragging EventHandlers for any node object
    public void dragNode(Node node) {
        // Custom object to hold x and y positions
        final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();

        node.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                dragDelta.x = node.getLayoutX() - mouseEvent.getSceneX();
                dragDelta.y = node.getLayoutY() - mouseEvent.getSceneY();
            }
        });

        node.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                node.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            }
        });

        node.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                node.setLayoutX(mouseEvent.getSceneX() + dragDelta.x);
                node.setLayoutY(mouseEvent.getSceneY() + dragDelta.y);
            }
        });

        node.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                node.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            }
        });
    }

    class Delta { double x, y; }
}
```